# is there a way to send mouse movements in windows powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, mouseevent

I wanna make a script that automatically moves the mouse and sends clicks to certain coordinates on the screen. It's mostly just for fun, but if anyone has any ideas that would be sick.

Comment: there are apparently ways to do it by invoking windows DLL stuff. it looks right nasty, so i don't recommend it. _however_, there are ways to do it that are fairly easy ... take a look at AutoIT and the PoSh module for it. [*grin*]

Comment: You may use a scripting tool what's made for this kind of tasks like [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com) or [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `Windows.Forms` Cursor class like so:

```
#Values are from your set resolution.
[Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = "2500, 1000"
```

to get your resolution you can use:

```
$screen = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::VirtualScreen
$screen.Width
$Screen.Height
```

Or just check your display settings lol

Youb  may have to load the .Net Class first:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
```

To left click, you can import the mouse event: See: [Cursor Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor?view=net-5.0)

```
Add-Type -MemberDefinition '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern void mouse_event(int flags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int info);' -Name U32 -Namespace W;
[W.U32]::mouse_event(6,0,0,0,0);
```